# What is the difference between monolithic and non-monolithic dc-dc converters?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, step-down

What is the difference between monolithic and non-monolithic dc-dc converters?
For example this is monolithic dc step down controller: [LTC3609](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3609)

Comment: Bruk, your question will become semi-useless if that link dies. Please add the relevant details into your post so that there's enough information there to answer your question. It will also save the rest of us having to "click".

Answer (score 3):

Monolithic in the sense of the part you have refers to the fact that the power switch(es) is(are) integrated into the controller IC as a single part. There are cases when you have to purchase the switches as external components.

In my opinion, a truly monolithic converter would be one that also integrates the inductor and possibly even the capacitors. I mean, look at all the stuff you have to add for the converter to work!

Comment: [This is what I call a monolithic switcher](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS82130)...

Answer (score 3):

Monolithic means that everything is on the same rock.

Comment: Agree. Where, in this context, "rock" refers to semiconductor die

Answer (score 2):

To be a little more specific, monolithic in this sense usually means that the power switches (FETs usually) are on the same silicon die as the control circuitry.

There are also converters that have several die in the same package, e.g. a controller and 2 FETs for a sync buck.  This might be transparent to the user as from the outside it seems like a single IC, but it is not referred to as a monolithic part.